# I'm unable to repack system.img after extraction

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, rom, mediatek

I extracted system.img of my rom using MTK extractor and edited a app then tried to repack but it failed. MTK extractor says system_unpack/file_contexts:No such directory found. Can anyone please tell me how to repack my system.img? I'm struck :/

Comment: you should use linux and loop mount the image for editing